# cooresponding coordinates for mises stress

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus

I used this code to extract stress at nodes and their corresponding coordinates but I'm not sure the coordinates are correct.

```
odb = visualization.openOdb('C:/Users/'+Name+'.odb')
frame=odb.steps['AStep'].frames[-1]

dispNode = odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets['UPPER']



TEMP= frame.fieldOutputs['S'].getSubset(position=ELEMENT_NODAL,region=dispNode).values
COORD= frame.fieldOutputs['COORD'].getSubset(region=dispNode).values
print(TEMP[1].mises)
print(COORD[1].data[0])
print(COORD[1].data[1])
print(COORD[1].data[2])
```

could you tell me is it right??

Comment: `TEMP` will hold separate values for the stress at the node from each element that shares the node.  Assuming the node is not on a material discontinuity interface or in a large gradient they will be approximately equal and you should just take an average.

Comment: also you can get your coordinates more directly as `dispNode[0].coordinates` (if you want a deformed coordinate you need to get the displacement from the fieldOutput and add it yourself )

Comment: how can I extract stress at nodes and its coordinates and save it? please write an example code.